# View Comments and/or Answers While Editing

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

Quite often, comments on a question ask for the original poster to add details.  For example:

> What architecture are you compiling for?
>
> What version of XYZ are you using?

I think it would be helpful for these comments to be visible while editing the original question.  That way, we won't have to keep going back and forth or open a new tab.

Comment: Another 'fix the system instead of the problem' request.  Ask well documented questions so that a couple of dozen users don't waste their time reading a poor one.  Making editing easier only produces more lazy questions.

Comment: @Hans I don't think it's fair for you to assume that.