# Could comments be shown on the edit [question/answer] page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, edits, user-interface

A lot of Stack Exchange sites treat comments as "suggested improvements" for questions and answers they're posted on, and users/mods will often suggest incorporating content from comments into the question or answer. However, since comments aren't visible while you're editing a question or answer, the only way to do this is to open the edit interface in a new browser tab and switch back and forth while editing.

Could the edit UI be enhanced to show comments (perhaps in read-only form) alongside the text being edited?

Comment: Comments are already shown to users with enough rep to edit posts directly (2k+ on designed sites, 1k+ on other sites including beta sites), as they get a special "inline" editor rather than having to go to a separate page to edit. This feature request is thus only applicable to users without enough rep to make edits directly.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog: Right, but some of these users will be editing their own answers or questions and thus able to make the edit without the rep or going through review queue. That was my situation today, integrating comments I'd written into my own answer after a mod suggested it.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Do you know why users with different editing privileges get different editors?

Comment: Related: [A much older feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96785/997587) asking for this and also viewing answers while editing.

Answer (score 5):

As of current writing (Nov 4, 2022, first appearance unknown), users *without* editing privilege can* see comments under the post now, similar to [the inline editor for users with editing privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97821/241919).

[image]
<sup>A comment under the post, note the editor guidance on the right for users without editing privilege</sup>

*they can also upvote, flag, and post comments from the editing page, whether it's intended or not, though probably not really an issue.

Comment: I also noticed that there are no links on the comment timestamps in this view. (I vaguely recall this being mentioned somewhere here on Meta SE, but I can't find any such post at the moment.)